# Minitest::UnexpectedError: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I have define a function foo on line 28 as follow:

```
def test_foo(strArray,valid=true)
```

and I am calling the function in two places in my code as follow:

```
arr1 = ["something","anotherthing"]
test_foo(arr1,false)
```

and in another place as follow:

```
arr2 = ["another","blah"]
test_foo(arr2)
```

here is the error I am getting when I run the test:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
     test/foo_test.rb:28:in `test_foo'
test/foo_test.rb:28:in `test_foo'
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Instead of pasting little bits of your code and telling us which lines they're on, can you instead just show us your `test/foo_test.rb` in its entirety? Also, it helps if you include the complete output generated by your failing test

Comment: @jon thank you for looking at this issue. Sorry for the code as the code was too big to paste and I thought it will give some enough information.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what is the issue. I named the function test_foo and minitest was treating a test function instead of helper function.

I renamed the helper function test_foo to check_foo and it passed al the test with no error.

Answer (score 0):

a little bit late but I have been in the same case.

The reason is that rails defines methods for executing tests with names starting with the same pattern you used: `test_*`

The transformation from `test(name, &block)` calls to function declarations can be found in the [declarative file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/declarative.rb)

Theses defined functions are then called for test executions.